# ¿Como utilizar split()?

Tags: java, string, split

Tengo un archivo .txt que se lee del cual necesito sacar separar en varias palabras

```
PRU.U,
 PRU.D,
 EJEM.T,
EJEM.C
```

Por ejemplo que `pru` sea igual a `prueba` y que `u` sea `uno` 
Y así en cada uno con sus respectivas palabras, pero no se como utilizar el `split` o `stringtokenizer`

//Este seria un ejemplo del texto que se lee

```
Ademasde    
PRU.U,
//      
 PRU.D,
//      
 EJEM.T,
//      
EJEM.C
```

a

```
    Scanner input;

try{

            input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Desktop\\EJEMPLO.txt"));

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = input.nextLine();

                String[] ON = line.split("\\stu.");
                for (int x = 0; x < ON.length; x++) {
                    String Tabla = "EJEMPLO ";

                    System.out.println(Tabla + ON[x].replace(",", ""));

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: No se acaba de entender si las palabras estan en la misma línea, en varias líneas, ni el resultado que esperas.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas corregir tu [expresion-regular](/questions/tagged/expresion-regular).

Con la línea

```
String line = input.nextLine();
```

ya estás separándole por líneas, es decir, la primera vez que lo llames obtendrás `PRU.U, //` en la variable `line`.

Usaremos la expresión regular `(\p{Alpha}*\.\p{Alpha}*).*` que se compone de los sigiuentes elementos:

1. `\p{_}` nos undica que buscaremos un grupo de caracteres, un sub-rango dentro de unicode.
2. `\p{Alpha}` nos indica que buscaremos caracteres alfanuméricos
3. el `*` nos indica que debe aparecer 0 o más veces
4. `\.` es el caracter punto.
5. `.` es cualquier caracter.
6. cualquier cosa entre paréntesis es un grupo, los numeramos de izquierda a derecha del 1 en adelante

Ahora en vez de hacer *split* haremos *replace* de la siguiente manera:

```
String nobreArchivo = line.replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha}*\\.\\p{Alpha}*).*","$1");
```

Donde si observas el segundo parámetro usa el signo de pesos para indicar que usaremos el resultado del número de grupo que especifiquemos, en nuestro caso solamente atrapamos un resultado en un grupo y es el que regresamos, el grupo 1.

### Addendum

Por si lo llegaras a ocupar, puedes usar igual los siguientes *matchers*:

- `\W` nos indica un carácter de palabra
- `\b` nos indica un inicio o fin de palabra (sí, puedes poner dos `\b` y lo que esté en medio asumirá que es parte de la misma palabra)